# How to change preferred network type with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the setting (or at least lead to the setting) for the preferred network type (4G, 3G, 2G). How can I do this?

Comment: I dont think flutter has the access to the hardware, it is only one UI framework. You should have to use `channel` to invoke `Android`/`IOS` API to change the network type. [Flutter Official Guide: Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: Indeed you should learn how to write a plugin or use the connectivity one https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity , however that doesn't allow you to change the setting , only to check for it